# Replacing current Storyboard with a new Storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uikit

I'm building an app and I've decided to build my user interfaces in multiple Storyboard files. Each Storyboard is a group of similar actions. For example, `LogInStoryboard` contains views for logging in and for registering a user.

I've run into a bit of problem with navigating to a new Storyboard and dismissing all the previous view controllers to clean up after myself.

This is my dataflow:

1) App launches into a log in view. Root view controller is `LogInViewController`, which lives in `LogInStoryboard`.

2) User taps the register button to summon the modal `RegistrationViewController`, also lives in `LogInStoryboard`.

3) User completes registration and is automatically signed in.

At this point, the view controller stack is `[LogInViewController, RegistrationViewController]`. After registering, the user is automatically signed in so I want to navigate to their home screen, `HomeViewController`. However, `HomeViewController` lives inside another Storyboard `HomeStoryboard`.

I want to dismiss both `LogInViewController` and `RegistrationViewController`, and then I want to instantiate `HomeViewController` from `HomeStoryboard` and present it. This way I have a simple view controller stack and the `LogInStoryboard` view controllers can all be deallocated.

What would be the best way to achieve this sort of flow? Or should I even be so worried about those old view controllers?

Comment: it really sounds like your looking for the coordinator pattern or flow controllers. even though you might have to change code, its def worth it. to better maneuver through your app and through the code!

Answer (score 4):

Its very often the case that your login flow acts almost as an entirely separate app who's only function is to authenticate the user and write the user info to your database.  In this case when you are done with the login instead of performing a segue what you want to do is replace the entire view hierarchy with `HomeViewController`.  To do this you can simply call `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow! = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()` (assuming you made `HomeViewController` the initial view controller).  Of course this has no animation and is kind of ugly so you way want to use [UIView.transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition) to animate the change instead.  Example:

```
    UIView.transition(with: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    })
```

Comment: I had considered doing this but I didn't like it for a couple reasons. First and foremost, it wouldn't cause both view controllers to call `deinit`. I suppose this is because they weren't properly dismissed. Secondly, but less importantly, I don't like manually modifying the `keyWindow`.

Comment: Looks like I was forgetting to call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` on the `keyWindow.rootViewController` Doing so dismissed all the presented view controllers and caused them to call `deinit` like I wanted. I think this solution will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0**

I would start with the HomeViewController as the *Initial View Controller*.
And from there create the *LogInViewController*.

```
if shouldLogin {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LogInStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let loginVCtrl = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourLogInViewControllerID")
    present(loginVCtrl, animated: true)
}
```

And after your user finished the Login/Registering process you can call:

```
dismiss(animated: true)
```

So your ViewController stack looks like:

1. [HomeViewController]
2. [HomeViewController, LogInViewController]
3. [HomeViewController]

Comment: I do like this solution as a concept. It would require a little bit of reworking of my app's architecture, though. I'll definitely keep it in the back of my mind; it may ultimately be the more elegant solution.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that best answer your questions by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

set your `HomeViewController` in `appdelegate` as `navigationcontroller` and set `navigationcontroller` as `rootviewcontroller`

NOTE: Both actions perform in `appdelegate`